# Accessing Controls Inside ASP.NET View Controls (Event Handling)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, events, listview, dynamic

If I have the following `ListView`, how can I attach a `SelectedIndexChanged` event listener to the `DropDownList` so I can perform a command on the respective object? Imagine I have a list of new users and I want to add them to a usergroup by selecting the group from the `DropDownList`.

```html
<asp:ListView ID="NewUsers" runat="server" DataSourceID="NewUsersSDS" DataKeyNames="ID">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:Table ID="groupPlaceholder" runat="server"><asp:TableRow></asp:TableRow></asp:Table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <GroupTemplate>
        <asp:TableCell ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:TableCell>
    </GroupTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Table ID="NewUsersTable" runat="server" Width="32%" CssClass="inlineTable">
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell Width="100px"><%# Eval("FullName").ToString.Trim()%></asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="RowIndex" runat="server" Value="<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>" />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="UserGroupSelect" runat="server" DataSourceID="UserGroupSelectSDS" DataValueField="ID" DataTextField="UserGroup"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="UserGroupSelect_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I've been having issues accessing controls inside of __View controls. I read in a few places that you could access them by `NewUsers.FindControl([ControlID as String])` but this doesn't seem to be working for me. I guess this is what's called a dynamic control? Not really sure, feeling a bit lost.

As always, your help is greatly appreciated. ;)

**Additional Info / Code**

```vb
'Now working code, thanks to James :)
Protected Sub ItemBind(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles NewUsers.ItemDataBound
    Dim lv As ListView = DirectCast(sender, ListView)
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem Then
        lv.DataKeys(e.Item.DataItemIndex).Value.ToString() 'get the datakey
    End If
End Sub
    Protected Sub UserGroupSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim RowIndex As Integer = CInt(DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, DropDownList).Parent.FindControl("RowIndex"), HiddenField).Value)
    Dim pk As Integer = CInt(NewUsers.DataKeys(RowIndex)("ID"))
    Try
        MessageBox("Update key " + pk.ToString, "Update Key") 'Custom js "alert" box function
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox("Something went wrong, is the update key empty?")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access controls in a ListView (or any databound control), you need to use `FindControl` on the item/row:

```
ListViewItem item = ListView1.Items[0];
if (item != null)
{
    DropDownList ddl = item.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
    if (ddl != null)
    {
        string value = ddl.SelectedValue;
    }
}
```

As for attaching a `SelectedIndexChanged` event, you can do it like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
        AutoPostBack="true" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(((HiddenField)((DropDownList)sender).Parent.FindControl("HiddenField1")).Value);

    ListViewItem item = ListView1.Items[rowIndex];
    if (item != null)
    {
        //your logic here
    }        
}
```

To retrieve a datakey:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(((HiddenField)((DropDownList)sender).Parent.FindControl("HiddenField1")).Value);

    int pk = (int)ListView1.DataKeys[rowIndex]["PrimaryKey"];     
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, so where does that top block of code go? Inside the `ItemDataBound` event for the `ListView`? Because certainly a `DropDownBox` control does not have an `ItemCommand` attribute. I'm still having trouble getting it to work. Will be posting more code in a bit after I try a few more ideas.

Comment: Yes, `ItemDataBound` would be a good place for it. Obviously, you won't need the part that gets the `ListViewItem`, because you'll already have it.

Comment: Oh sorry, you need to add `AutoPostBack="true"`

Comment: Everything works beautifully now, except for one glitch with the page life cycle. The problem is the `SelectedIndexChanged` fires AFTER the `ItemDataBound` and as a result, the item that I just acted on remains on the page until the next PostBack. Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks ;)

Comment: ItemDataBound should only be called on the first page load, shouldn't it? Are you rebinding after every postback?

Comment: Well I don't have `If Not IsPostBack` anywhere on this particular page if that's what you mean. I still have some confusion about when and where to use it. The following events are firing, in this order: `Init`, `Load`, `LayoutCreated`, `DataBinding`, `ItemCreated` ... , `DataBound`, `PreRender`, `Load`, `SelectedIndexChanged`, and `PreRender` again. That's after wrapping my `ItemDataBound` event instructions in the `If Not IsPostBack` condition for the `ListView`. This occurs after I select an item from the `DropDownList`.

Comment: Add the If Not Page.IsPostBack around the code that binds the ListView. You use that when you only want code to be executed on the first page load, which is most of the time, aside from dynamic content which has to be loaded everytime the page loads. That's probably the simplest way to explain it.

Comment: The first page load is for initialization of the page, and it's controls.

Comment: So I guess this means to set my `DataSourceID` for the `ListView` programmatically then rather than declaratively so I can control when it's bound? Because currently I just let that happen automatically, as you can see in my markup... but wait, wouldn't this mean the `ListView` wouldn't be regenerated and therefore have the same Items?

Comment: After handling the index changed, try to rebind the ListView (or datasource control) to reflect the updates.

Comment: Psshh... well that was easy, lol. I simply added `NewUsers.DataBind()` to the end of my `SelectedIndexChanged` function and now everything is good. You've been far more than helpful. Can't tell you how much I appreciate it. Thanks James :D